# Purely functional languages?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming

what is purely functional language? And what is purely functional data structure?
I'm kind of know what is the functional language, but I don's know what is the "pure" mean. Does anyone know about it?
Can someone explain it to me?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When functional programmers refer to the concept of a *pure* function, they are referring to the concept of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).

Referential transparency is actually about value substitution without changing the behaviour of the program.

Consider some function that adds 2 to a number:

```
let add2 x = x + 2
```

Any call to `add2 2` in the program can be substituted with the value `4` without changing any behaviour.

Now consider we throw a `print` into the mix:

```
let add2 x =
    print x 
    x + 2
```

This function still returns the same result as the previous one but we can no longer do the value substitution without changing the program behaviour because `add2 2` has the side-effect of printing `2` to the screen.

It is therefore not refentially transparent and thus an impure function.

Now we have a good definition of a pure function, we can define a purely functional language as a language where we work pretty much exclusively with pure functions.

**Note:** It is still possible to perform effects (such as printing to the console) in a purely functional language but this is done by treating the effect as a **value** that represents the action to be performed rather than as a side-effect within some function.  These effect values are then composed into a larger set of program behaviour.

---

A purely functional data structure is then simply a data structure that is designed to be used from a purely functional language.

Since mutating a data structure with a function would break this referential transparency property, we need to return a new data structure each time we e.g. add or remove elements.

There are particular types of data structures where we can do this efficiently, sharing lots of memory from prior copies: singly-linked lists and various tree based structures are the most common examples but there are many others.

Comment: Is this _effect value_ always of a special type like `IO` in Haskell?

Comment: @ftor Yes, you would have a special type for this.  It could be `IO` like in Haskell and some popular Scala implementations, F# has `Async` for asynchronous effects while Purescript uses `Eff`/`Aff` for synchronous/asynchronous effects.

Comment: @TheInnerLight if the function only do one math function and there are no other features, it will consider the pure function? In the add2, the x is not pure data structure right? X changed from 2 to 4. Can you give a example of the pure data structure? I do not clearly understand it.

Comment: @JeffYan No, `x` did not change.  In this case, `x` can absolutely be just a simple immutable value, we don't change it, we just return a new value equal to `x+2`.  I wouldn't really consider it a purely functional data structure though, when we talk about purely functional data structures, we are usually talking about collections of many immutable values.

Answer (score -2):

Most functional languages that are in use today are not pure in that they provide ways to interact with the real world. Long ago, for example, Haskell had a few pure variants.

***Purely functional data*** = persistent data (i.e. immutable)

***Pure function*** = given the same input always produces same output and does not contain, or is effected by, side effects.

Comment: There is absolutely no issue with purely functional languages interacting with the real world, that's a damaging misconception.  Such languages simply don't do so via the side-effecting functions which most other languages use.  Haskell's approach to IO involves interacting with the real world without requiring the use of impure functions.

Comment: @TheInnerLight - You clearly are not reading my answer with objectiveness or context. Whether IO is an add-on or part of the core grammar is irrelevant to the SO question.

Comment: Of course I am.  Your answer suggests that a language could not be considered purely functional if it interacts with the real world, I am explaining to you that that inference is false.  Retributive downvoting will not change that.